# Training keras with tensorflow: Redundancy in labelling the object or multiple labels on same object

Tags: tensorflow, keras, object-detection, tensorboard, keras-2

I was training `keras` with `tensorflow` for person detection. After the training, when the testing was done so many images contains redundant labeling of person. ie; for a single person in an image, multiple labeling as a person was shown. What is the actual reason behind this?

My training set contains nearly 2000 images, a single class `person`, `batch=32`, `epoch=100`, `threshold=0.55` and `testing images=250`.

Comment: Have you heard about [`non-maximal suppresion`](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/16/faster-non-maximum-suppression-python/)?

Comment: What is the actual reason behind redundancy. Can it be reduced while training itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overtraining of samples may lead to redundancy and if you are using different angles of an image, for example if you train for detecting people and you are providing samples of human from different angles, then it may show errors on detection in real cases. If this is not the issue, then non- maximal suppression will be the better option.